# Amazon S3 bucket file upload : Invalid Transfer encoding header

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 bucket as per [this](https://gist.github.com/chrismdp/6c6b6c825b07f680e710) example. I have created a shell script and changed param values, when I try to execute it, following error message is returned:

```
<Error><Code>NotImplemented</Code>
<Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message>
<Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>
```

From the docs, it seems `curl` adds this header when it can't determine the content length. I don't know whether it's possible to change curl config to skip including Transfer Encoding header, but have tried the following:

- Changed content type to multipart
- Included content length header
- Removed content type header

I am still getting the same error. Do I need to change anything else to make it work?

Comment: Can you `echo` the entire curl command and arguments before executing it?

Comment: @helloV you don't know how much this comment has helped me. I added echo and found that I was not passing all the parameters (filename was missing). Thanks for the help, I would have accepted this as a correct answer had you posted it as an answer :)

Comment: Now posted as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [NotImplemented](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/15)  it is possible you are not passing the filename or `Body` is an empty string.

Can you echo the entire `curl` command and arguments before executing it?

Comment: Filename was an empty string and hence, curl didn't include content length and added Transfer-Encoding instead.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur , when we mess up with the formats of the params , I got the same error when i didn't stringify my JSON body in node js.