# Upload stream to Amazon s3 using nodejs SDK v3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to upload a stream to s3 using the AWS SDK v3.

The PutObjectRequest as [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/modules/putobjectrequest.html) should accept a ReadableStream, but every time I receive the error `NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented` - the header reported is `Transfer-Encoding`.

[This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549415/amazon-s3-bucket-file-upload-invalid-transfer-encoding-header) suggests that I'm providing an empty body, but it's supposed to accept ReadableStream (Archiver provides a Transform stream).

I have created a minimal (non) working example. I have also tried putting `client.send()` with a callback instead, but with the same response.

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import archiver from 'archiver'

async function run() {
  const archive = archiver('zip')

  const client = new S3Client({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION })

  // create a stream destination for aws
  // also pipe to aws
  try {
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_BUCKET,
      Key: 'testupload.zip',
      // set the content type as we're streaming it
      ContentType: 'application/zip',
      // body should take a readable stream
      Body: archive,
    })
    client.send(command, (err, data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error uploading package to S3')
    console.error(err)
    res.status(501).json({ message: 'Error configuring upload to s3' })
  }

  archive.file('/fixtures/harambe.jpg', { name: 'harambe.jpg' })

  archive.finalize()
}

run()
```

Comment: You need to pipe the stream - are you sure `const archive = archiver('zip')` gives you a readable stream?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary as per the Archiver library, it uses the [`readable-stream`](https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream) library which is supposed to be a 'cut' from Node 10. Maybe the problem is with this underlying library? I will try to reproduce with a vanilla readable stream.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary it seems that is indeed the issue. Thank you for triaging this – extremely helpful! I will raise with the developer of Archiver.

Comment: @JoshKopecek This seems to be answered, but I'm not sure if the answer is that you need to pipe the stream or the archiver('zip') wasn't giving you a usable stream. It may be helpful to others to provide a proper answer.

Comment: @ptoinson I'll provide an answer now. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @JoshKopecek Did you eventually find a way to work with archiver and S3's v3 SDK? If so would you mind sharing it? I'd love to avoid downgrading to v2 just for this. Cheers.

Comment: @CB-Dan we actually switched away from S3 completely to Google Storage. IMHO it provided much better APIs and interfaces. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the Archiver library uses a static version of `readable-stream` from Node 10, which is not compatible with the AWS SDK version.

When it pipes to the Archiver instance, it fails.